# Access/Refresh token confusion

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I've been doing a lot of reading on this subject and I can see that there are many different opinions and approaches to authenticating using JWT.

My understanding is as follows:
In its simplest form, a JWT authentication mechanism should:

1. Verify username and password.
2. Create a signed JWT access token containing information (depending on the app's needs) on the user.
3. Send that token in the response.
4. The client then stores the token (which from my understanding there is some debate whether a secure cookie or localStorage is more secure), and sends it with each request's headers.
5. The server can then authorize the user using middleware verifying the JWT. No state, all information in contained within the JWT.

Assuming the JWT has no expiration (or perhaps a very long expiration date, maybe a couple of months), it sounds good because I can provide the user a persistent logged in state for a long time. The concern is, to my understanding, if the JWT was to be stolen, it is essentially an unlimited access card and a huge security breach.

So that's where the refresh token enters, the server issues both refresh and access tokens (refresh token with a long/unlimited expiration and the access token short).

The server database holds some kind of table of valid refresh tokens (so that if one is stolen it can be invalidated easily) and when issuing a new access token, validates the refresh token.

This also adds the need to add some sort of countdown mechanism on the front end where a refresh request is to be sent to the server prior to the access token expiration date so that the user won't be logged out.

And my question:

Why? If we go through all the trouble of creating a db table for refresh tokens, why not just make a table of valid access tokens and invalidate them if needed? How is that less secure than using refresh tokens?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Access tokens aren't primarily used to provide extra security, but to provide *efficiency* and *decoupling*.

An access token can have a very short lifetime - maybe even less than a minute - but be used to authenticate multiple requests to different services within that time. Those services don't need to have any access to the authentication database, because they can trust the access token until its expiry date; that makes them faster and simpler.

For instance, if you're using a dynamic page with lots of AJAX requests, that might run in very quick succession. Those AJAX calls might be implemented as serverless functions (e.g. AWS Lambda), or as standalone scripts in different programming languages on different servers, or you might just want to make them as efficient as possible, and avoid any database access. The only information that needs to be shared between them is a public key to verify the signature on the JWTs they receive.

From a security a point of view, this is a trade-off: on the one hand, an access token for a user whose access has been revoked can still be used until it expires; on the other hand, the long-lived refresh token is transmitted much less than a traditional session token, so there are fewer chances for it to be intercepted.

To address your concrete concern:

> This also adds the need to add some sort of countdown mechanism on the front end where a refresh request is to be sent to the server prior to the access token expiration date so that the user won't be logged out.

No "countdown" is needed. The code that has access to both tokens simply looks at its current access token before using it; if it has expired, or is about to expire, it requests a new one using the refresh token. It then gets a new access token, and probably a renewed refresh token - the expiry date on the refresh token represents how long the user can be idle before they are automatically logged out.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to make a table of access tokens and it is dangerous to secure. 
We have to save only refresh token and add one field for valid/invalid in the table. And send access token and refresh token to the client side. 
The clients send access token with each request's headers.
The server can authorize the user using middleware verifying the JWT.
After some time, the access token will be expired(access token's expired time is shorter than the refresh token's expired time).
The client sends refresh token to server.
Then the client will get new access token using refresh token(refresh token should be recreated, in other words, we can use only one-time refresh token, we have to update table of refresh token with new refresh token).
The client can get new access token and refresh token.

I hope it will be help you.